# MVC 5 CKEditor SetData to editor from DB

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, asp.net-mvc-5

Almost got everything working with CKEditor plugin and the only problem left is to load the data already saved to the DB into the WYSIWYG editor.

If i try something like this in javascript as a test it works fine.

```
<script>
    var value = "<h1>Awesome</h1>";

    var config = {};
    editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo('editor', config, html);

    editor.setData(value);
</script>
```

So this creates the editor and actually tries to load the "html" variable into it but this is currently just empty.

So if I look in my DB I have a field called Description (nvarchar(max),null) which currently has this value: `<h1>Awesome</h1>`

But if I try to get this value in Javascript I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

And if i look at the console log it looks like this:

```
 var value = '<h1>Awesome</h1>
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 
';
```

Comment: Can you show more complete code on how you're trying to set this value?  What's throwing the syntax error?  Generally you can create a JavaScript variable from a model property in your view very simply:  `var value = '@Model.Value';`

Comment: It's really not much more code to show. The code is inside a edit click function. So I think its abit wierd that I get the error on page load. But can update the post a little bit.

Comment: Yea, if I just try something like alert('@Model.Note.Notes_ID'); it works fine.

Comment: Smells a lot like like a non-printing illegal character! I've had plenty of those bastards. It could be `\r` or `BOM` for example. Try rewriting the value in the database and also the `var value = '@HTML.Raw(Model.Note.Description)';` - *Don't copypaste it*, delete it and the newlines around it and type it again. The next step is to examine the value and the code around it in a hex editor. Also turn your editor to show invisible characters, in Visual Studio this is `Edit > Advanced > View White Space`. Also make sure that your database value does NOT have any newlines in it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

Ok, after some experimenting I managed to create a working solution.

I created a hidden field for the Description

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Note.Description)
```

And I am showing it like this:

```
<div id="editorcontents" class="well padding-10">
  @Html.Raw(Model.Note.Description)
</div>
```

And when I go into edit mode I hide the editor and set the value to the editor from the hidden field.

```
if (editor)
    return;

$('#editorcontents').hide();
var config = {};
var html = $('#Note_Description').val();

editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo('editor', config, html);
```

And in the success method of my ajax update function I destroy the editor and update the value in the hidden field.

```
success: function (data) {
   editor.destroy();
   editor = null;
   $('#Note_Description').val(data[2].Description);
}
```

So somehow getting the value with Jquery fixed the problem.